# Windows Universal Apps interaction behavior in resource dictionary

Tags: c#, xaml, datatemplate, resourcedictionary, win-universal-app

I am having hard time understanding why the following XAML code doesn't work if I put it in a resource dictionary.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Holding">
                    <lbehavior:OpenMenuFlyoutAction/>
                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                <MenuFlyout>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="edit" Command="{Binding EditCommand}"/>
                </MenuFlyout>
            </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource VibeSiteTextBlockStyle}" Margin="0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Url}" Style="{StaticResource VibeSiteTextBlockStyle}" Margin="0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

The same XAML works fine if I place it in a pages resources (`Page.Resources`).  The error message is:

"Exception = {Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException: The text associated with this error code could not be found.

The attachable property '%0' was not found in type '%1'. [Line: 11 Position: 37]}

Comment: Have you declared that resource dictionary in App.xaml?

Comment: Yes I did.  I included the resource dictionary as merge dictionary in app.xaml.